# Handling suspended user creating new accounts

Tags: discussion

If a user whose account has been "[temporarily suspended](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) to cool down" creates a new account to continue unabated, is there someone interested in knowing this?

Comment: Flag for moderators?

Comment: Your question has already been answered, but from an actual mod POV: oh, yes, if anyone is interested in knowing, it's whomever suspended the user in the first place ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just use a custom moderator flag to show what is going on.

We don't do public shaming; if nothing else, you might accuse the wrong person.
Leave it to the moderators. They have the means to discover if your suspicion is correct, and the means to act upon it.